# "Forward must problems" explanation in compiler design

Tags: dataflow, compiler-construction

While studying, I came across the following statements:

A join point is a program point where two branches meet.

Available expressions is a forward, must problem.

Forward = Data Flow from in to out.

Must = At joint point, property must hold on all paths that are joined.

I get what joint point, available expression and forward is. But I am getting what exactly is meant by MUST.

Someone please explain what MUST is with example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
a = 10
if condition
  x = a + 1  // First calculation only in true branch.
else
  x = 3
end
y = a + 1    // Can we eliminate this redundant calculation?
```

Here, the arithmetic expression `a + 1` is calculated two times. The goal of the available expression analysis is to figure out whether one of these calculations can be eliminated by reusing the previously calculated value. If it is possible to eliminate the calculation, the compiler can optimize the code to hold the reusable calculation result in a register.

To eliminate the redundant calculation, the following conditions have to be fulfilled:

- No variable that is used in the calculation has been reassigned between the calculations. In the given example `a` is not reassigned.
- The expression is guaranteed to be calculated on all path that lead to the statement where the expression is eliminated. Here, the expression is only calculated in the `true` branch, but not in the `false` branch. Thus, if the condition was false, `a + 1` has not yet been calculated, which means that we cannot eliminate the calculation.

This is a *forward* analysis, since we run over the flow control graph from the top to the bottom. It is a *must* analysis, since the expression has to be calculated on all path that lead to the calculation that should be eliminated.